# How should mean and standard deviation be tracked over time

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

Say we have a process where not all data is available at the beginning, and we need to estimate mean and standard deviation to normalize them, what would be the update for the tracking variables?

Somehow I feel that the mean we can just track it with a simple average:
$$
\mu_{t+1} = \frac{\mu_t \cdot t + \mu^\text{batch}}{t+1}
$$

but doing so also for the std seems wrong, and I have a feel that i should use some second moment estimation